# How to get a ListView to scroll with ScrollableTabView?

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to get a proof of concept working with a list of elements. The list renders fine, but when I try to scroll to the bottom of the list, I'm unable to get all the way to the end. Is there a solution to this? I've set the ScrollView to have a flex: 1 style, and the ListView inside also has the flex set to 1. When I try without the ScrollableTabView package, the scrolling works, so I assume I'm doing something wrong with how I'm styling this page. Any suggestions would be great!

Here's my stripped down code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScrollableTabView, {ScrollableTabBar, } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScrollableTabView, {ScrollableTabBar, } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NativeAppEventEmmiter,
  ListView,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
class whistle extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', 'row 3', ])
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <ScrollableTabView
                 style={{marginTop: 20, }}
                 initialPage={0}
                 renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
           >
                <View tabLabel='List'>
                 <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <ListView
                      style={styles.container}
                      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                      renderRow={(data) => <View><Text>{data}</Text></View>}
                    />
                 </ScrollView>
              </View>
           </ScrollableTabView>
      </View>

      );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: 20,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you nest ListView in ScrollView because only 1 PanResponder will works, the only use case of nesting it is when one of them is working horizontally & second one vertically.

There is lots of useless components, you can try it like this

`<View>
    <ScrollableTabView
        style={styles.container}
        initialPage={0}
        renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
    >
        <ListView
            tabLabel='List'
            style={styles.container}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(data) => <Text>{data}</Text>}
        />

    </ScrollableTabView>
</View>`

should work properly but didn't check it cuz wrote from finger ;)